# Moving the x-axis / chart to the right in MS Excel

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office, linechart

In MS Excel 2010, I have the following data. I created a simple line chart but it uses the data axis automatically (that's what I want). The problem is that the first date (11/25/2015) is right below 0% (of the y-axis) and I don't want that to happen. I want to move the middle area of the chart along with the x-axis a bit to the right so that it doesn't look shabby. How to go about doing this?

I added a new row and then deleted it but the chart automatically adjusts by itself. I have also tried simply resizing the chart. I've also tried creating new rows but I don't know if that's the right way.

[Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIFjb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select your X axis and right click on it and then select Format Axis from the pop up menu.

[image: example format axis menu option]

in the options screen that comes up on the right you can set your MAX and MIN values so your chart does not resize on you at all or you can limit how much it can resize in one direction.  You can also set where the AXIS crosses.  now this will apply to where the Y axis crosses.

[image: Axis Format Options]

This information can be set for the Y axis as well by selecting it and repeating this process.  When you do it for the Y axis, you are controlling where the X axis will cross.

Comment: I got what you did there. It did work. I was able to set the x-axis bounds. Thank you!